# How can I call a placeholder in the task.py into the test_task.py using Unittest?

Tags: python-unittest

### Iam using pycharm, JetBrains Academy plug -in and Unittest.

I wanto to be able to verify with a test if a student wrote the accurate response inside the placeholder.
This for k-12 students. I am learning `Unittest`. Sorry if this is too basic; I tried to solve it in many ways.

I reviewed "Course creator start guide" https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/10081-jetbrains-academy/docs/educator-start-guide.html?section=Python

In all the examples you call the Test case with the following:

```
import unittest
from ..task import test_sum


class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(3, test_sum(1, 2), msg="1 + 2 = 3")
```

Is there a way to reference the placeholder without creating a function?
Example if as a task I have:

```
print("Hello, world")
```

With the place holder in `print` How can I create a test to verify the students response?
I have this code in my test_task.py

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test(self):
        self.assertEqual(print, print)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The test is marked as correct, but is not calling the task.py

I was expecting to be able to use assertEqual to verify the correct answer in the place holder "print"
I have reviewed these two resources and have yet to be successful.

https://codeberryschool.com/blog/en/python-unittest/
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=He0WiNq1Ddc

I also tried import unittest2 and test_helper

Thank you so much!